# changing the property value of component through observable in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have two components that share a service, first component has  2 buttons which triggers 2 methods on click `squeezeContent()` and `unsqueezeContent()`, these methods pass a numeric value to observable in the service, this value is then substracted from property in another component which shares the same service, i have been trying to figure out to use observable but i am not doing it right

**first component**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CrosspropertiesService } from "../services/crossproperties.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-timer',
  templateUrl: './timer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timer.component.css']
})
export class TimerComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('timerBody') timerBody:ElementRef;
    constructor(private crossproperties: CrosspropertiesService ) { }
        public timerBodyHeight:number;
        ngAfterViewInit() {
            this.timerBodyHeight = this.timerBody.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
         }
         squeezeContent(){
            this.crossproperties.resizeHeight(this.timerBodyHeight);
         }
         unsqueezeContent(){
             this.crossproperties.resizeHeight(0);
         }
}
```

**and service file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class CrosspropertiesService {
  private subject  = new Subject<any>();

  resizeHeight(height:number){
    this.subject.next({ value: height });
  }
  getSidebarScrollHeight(): Observable<any>{
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
  constructor() { }
}
```

**second component**

```
import { Component, OnInit , OnDestroy, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { CrosspropertiesService } from '../services/crossproperties.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar-expanded',
  templateUrl: './sidebar-expanded.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar-expanded.component.css']
})
export class SidebarExpandedComponent implements OnInit {
  subscription:Subscription;
  private sidebarscrollheight:number;
  constructor(private crossproperty: CrosspropertiesService) {
    this.subscription = this.crossproperty.getSidebarScrollHeight().subscribe(height => { this.sidebarscrollheight = this.sidebarscrollheight - height; });
  }
  ngOnInit() {  
   this.sidebarscrollheight = 600; //computed value in this section
  }  
}
```

now i want the **sidebarscrollheight property** value to be changed when **squeezeContent() and unsqueezeContent()** method in component 1 calls the fucntion in service , **sidebarscrollheight property** already has some computed value , any help please

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial in the Angular 2 Docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

That will help you understand how to communicate between components via observables. Also, remember to unsubscribe e.q. `this.subscription.unsubscribe()` from your observables.